# Plotting residuals (continuous) vs explanatory variable (categorical) warning: "In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion"

Tags: r, plot, statistics, mixed-models, coercion

Long time googler, first time asker, sorry if my question formatting isn't great.

I have a tibble called daily , here is the dput output:

```
structure(list(Moon_Phase = c("mid", "mid", "mid", "mid", "mid", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new"), name = c("Al_Capone", "Al_Capone", "Bonnie", 
"Clyde", "Clyde", "Al_Capone", "Al_Capone", "Barb", "Barb", "Biggie", 
"Biggie", "Bonnie", "Bowser", "Bowser", "Doe", "Doe", "Jesse", 
"Jesse", "Lizzie", "Lizzie", "Louise", "Louise", "Roxy", "Roxy", 
"Sue", "Sue"), `date(DateTime)` = structure(c(17215, 17216, 17156, 
17155, 17156, 17133, 17134, 17161, 17162, 17157, 17158, 17156, 
17216, 17217, 17199, 17200, 17161, 17162, 17185, 17186, 17133, 
17134, 17196, 17197, 17193, 17194), class = "Date"), count = c(60970.2127659574, 
47145.2054794521, 66323.6514522822, 51168.932038835, 64211.673151751, 
75354.5454545455, 76069.5652173913, 52992, 42865.1162790698, 
63810.6870229008, 70530.612244898, 54834.2379958246, 60198.4962406015, 
56254.2056074766, 70338.4615384615, 64800, 44400, 57466.6666666667, 
54477.8761061947, 46423.8805970149, 58830.7692307692, 70478.0487804878, 
62786.4406779661, 66541.935483871, 58493.4306569343, 60781.3953488372
), avg = c(0.167566808400667, 0.0916716980460977, 0.169983135592288, 
0.0950009067366473, 0.172076034264729, 0.195215802633862, 0.213308643950517, 
0.160601492425918, 0.0352463837761031, 0.181835110358351, 0.175611555735529, 
0.102218432032213, 0.141489253083123, 0.129562604439575, 0.169391188107789, 
0.148380507250866, 0.158557388456314, 0.146077250703009, 0.120220050003983, 
0.0801402704143268, 0.15458396257616, 0.192381143851207, 0.165149903514201, 
0.138869248196884, 0.137792634329098, 0.15698540693065)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), vars = c("Moon_Phase", 
"name"), drop = TRUE)
```

I created a linear model:

```
m0 <- lm(count ~ Moon_Phase, data = daily)
```

I want to check the independence of my model, so I plotted residuals vs the explanatory variable:

```
plot(x = daily$Moon_Phase,
     y = E1,
     xlab = "Moon Phase",
     ylab = "Normalized residuals",
     xlim = c(0,nrow(daily))
)
```

I also want to check whether I need to include daily$name as a random effect, so I compared the residuals of the random effect-less linear model with the potential random effect:

```
lm.test <- lm(count ~ Moon_Phase, data = daily)
lm.test.resid <- rstandard(lm.test)
```

and plotted that:

```
plot(lm.test.resid ~ daily$name, 
     xlab = "Name",
     ylab = "Standardized residuals",
     xlim = c(0,nrow(daily)))
```

Each time I used plot(), I got the following warning message:

> Warning message: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs
>   introduced by coercion

Does anyone know why that message is appearing? I've seen on here and other forums that other people have had this issue, and converting things to factors and/or numeric seem to help other people, so I've tried `as.numeric(E1)`, `as.factor(daily$Moon_Phase)`, and `as.factor(daily$name)`, but that hasn't seemed to help.

Thanks!

Comment: `lm.test.resid ~ as.factor(daily$name)` in the last plot command works for me.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I was misusing as.factor(); I was just running as.factor(daily$name) as its own line rather than daily$name <- as.factor(daily$name) or what you did. I have it running correctly now.